# Trying to call reverseGeocodeLocation, but program keeps jumping over function call. Any ideas?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, reverse-geocoding, mapquest

Here is my code and the full context in which I am trying to call reverseGeocodeLocation:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = 
[self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

CLLocation *destination = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:touchMapCoordinate.latitude longitude:touchMapCoordinate.longitude];

__block CLGeocoder *destinationPin = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
__block NSString *destinationPinName;

[destinationPin reverseGeocodeLocation:destination completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
    {
        CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *addressTxt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@",
                                [topResult subThoroughfare],[topResult thoroughfare],
                                [topResult locality], [topResult administrativeArea]];

        destinationPinName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:addressTxt];
    }
}];

annotation = [[MQAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:destinationPinName andCoordinate:touchMapCoordinate];
```

I have breakpoints set up at the function entry points, within both if-blocks in the function, and after the function where I assign annotation. When I get to the reverseGeocodeLocation block destinationPin has a valid value, but my program keeps jumping straight to the break point set after the function call. Any ideas what might be happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution of `reverseGeocodeLocation` is done asynchronously. When that background task is complete, your completion block will be called. So what you are seeing is correct behavior. The call to `reverseGeocodeLocation` returns immediately, long before it is complete and long before your completion handler is called. You need to update your code so your annotation is created in the completion handler.